# Generic linear search in Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I have to "Implement the following generic method for linear search" but as far as I know it's not possible to have a generic array. None of my classmates have been able to figure it out and neither has the TA for our class. Is this possible, and if so can you point me in the right direction?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String type = scan.next();
    int length = scan.nextInt();
    
    //checks the type and makes the appropriate array
    if (type.equals("I")) {
        int[] anArray = new int[length];
        for (int i = 0; i<length; i++) {
            anArray[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        int key = scan.nextInt();
        linearSearch(anArray, key); //Error, the method is not applicable for the arguments
    }
}

public static <E extends Comparable<E>> int linearSearch(E[] list, E key) {
    for (int i = 0; i<list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].equals(key)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can't *create* a generic array in Java.
- You most certainly *can* work with generic references to arrays.
- The problem with the code as-shown is that you have a primitive array and generics can only work with references.

If you use `Integer[]` instead of `int[]` the program will work.

Answer (score 1):

The elements of the array must be objects implementing Comparable, so you should use an Integer array:

```
Integer[] anArray = new Integer[length];
```

Answer (score 1):

Generics is not allowed to work with primitives, you will nedd to use a wrapper Integer class and therefore

```
Integer[] anArray = new Integer[length];
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to make `anArray` of type `Comparable` and `java.lang.Integer` has `Comparable` type. The code:

```
package com.stackoverflow.json;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String type = scan.next();
        int length = scan.nextInt();

        // checks the type and makes the appropriate array
        if (type.equals("I")) {
            Integer[] anArray = new Integer[length];
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                anArray[i] = scan.nextInt();
            }
            int key = scan.nextInt();
            Comparable result = linearSearch(anArray, key); // Error, the method is not applicable
                                        // for the arguments
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }

    public static <E extends Comparable<E>> int linearSearch(E[] list, E key) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i].equals(key)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Prints:

```
I
4
12
3
4
6
3
1
```

Note that `result` is index of searched element in array `anArray`